# Use of Classes in Cocos2d-x to create an "Enemy" to extend Layer

Tags: android, c++, ios, cocos2d-x

Pretty new to Cocos2dx and C++ from an Objective-C background.  I'm making a game where you can have between 1-10 enemies on the screen at a time.  Each enemy has 1 sprite for its body and 2 stats (health & damage).

In the past with Objective-C I've been able to define a Class.h/Class.mm file and fill it with as many variables as I want (health, speed, height, weight, color, etc), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this in Cocos2dx.

Here is a simplified project that isolates the problem I'm having.  I'm sure it's something straight forward but I'm having trouble looking up the solution

```
//-----Enemy.h
#include "cocos2d.h"
USING_NS_CC;
class Enemy : public cocos2d::Layer{
public:
    virtual bool init();
    CREATE_FUNC(Enemy);
    void setHealth(int val);

private:
    int myHealth;
    Sprite *body;
    Sprite *weapon;

};

//-----Enemy.cpp
#include "Enemy.h"
USING_NS_CC;

bool Enemy::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
        return false;
    return true;
}

void setHealth(int newHealth)
{
    //myHealth = newHealth;
}

//-----HelloWorldScene.h
#include "cocos2d.h"
USING_NS_CC;
class HelloWorld : public cocos2d::Layer
{
public:
    static cocos2d::Scene* createScene();
    virtual bool init();  
    CREATE_FUNC(HelloWorld);

};

//-----HelloWorldScene.cpp
#include "HelloWorldScene.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include "Enemy.h"
USING_NS_CC;

Scene* HelloWorld::createScene()
{
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = HelloWorld::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
    if ( !Layer::init() )
        return false;
    Enemy *newEnemy = Enemy::create();
    //newEnemy->setHealth(100);
    this->addChild(newEnemy);
    return true;
 }
```

This compiles fine except for the 2 commented lines, which cause errors.

Please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: what errors exactly?

Comment: "myHealth = newHealth;" in Enemy.cpp returns the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'myHealth'", which tells me that my declaration of myHealth in the private section of the Enemy class is not accessible.  Calling the function "newEnemy->setHealth(100);" returns a 'clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1', which tells me I'm not using the proper syntax to invoke a function within the Enemy class.  I'm just converting an Objective-C blurb into C++ syntax, but the architecture is different so I'm not sure how it should be structured for C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your error message exactly, it looks like you are missing the class name in your `setHealth` method in Enemy.cpp

Change your method declaration in your Enemy.h

From:

```
void setHealth(int val);
```

To:

```
void setHealth(int newHealth);
```

Then in your Enemy.cpp file change the following.

From:

```
void setHealth(int newHealth)
```

To:

```
void Enemy::setHealth(int newHealth)
```

Comment: The Enemy::setHealth did it.  Thanks much, I've been stuck on this for 2 hours just doing random things hoping it would work :)